# How to run an installed file after installation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

I have a setup project in c#. i want that setup run 2 exe file from the installed files after installation. How can i set which file to be run after installation.

Any suggestion would be highly appriciated

Comment: To be honest just one of my questions were answered correctly. But you'r right. i set the answer as accepted one.

Comment: @maryam : If you have found better answers for your questions just post them and accept them. That would help if somebody else have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom action as below...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the install complete, it should run the application automatically.

[Launching Your Application After Install using Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx)