# .NET Open txt file after installation

Tags: .net, installation

I'm creating a .NET installer using SetupProject of VS2008.
I can force my execute file to run after installation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460628/how-to-run-an-installed-file-after-installation).
But I don't know how to force a display of Readme.txt. When I add a text file for custom action, it always tells me that the file is not supported for custom action.

What should I do? I do not want to create a batch file for this task to invoke the display of txt file.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could just call cmd.exe which is always there

Answer (score 0):

Just like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414956/how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-installation), but you can call:

```
cmd /k start <path to ReadMe.txt>
```

not sure, maybe even `start <path to ReadMe.txt>` or `explorer <path to ReadMe.txt>` will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did as instructed in the post. After the installation it shows the cmd window, which is so ugly and make the user be concerned about a black windows shown up without reason.

Comment: what about `explorer <path to ReadMe.txt>`?